# Copying multiple file from folder to s3 excluding few folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to copy the multiple files inside a folder from ec2 to s3 bucket.

Folder structure is this,

```
└───data
    ├───201707
            |
            |__ new
            |
            |__ new1
```

I want to copy ONLY the contents of the `201707` folder, so i used below command:

```
aws s3 cp data/ s3://bucket-name/data/201707/ --recursive --exclude 'data/new/*' --exclude 'data/new1/*'
```

but the output in s3 had a new and new1 folder, what will be the right command to exclude these folders?

Answer (score 5):

The `--exclude` and `--include` arguments for the `s3` aws-cli subcommand takes in a *pattern*, not simply a path prefix.

```
--exclude (string) Exclude all files or objects from the command that matches the specified pattern.
```

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

```
The following pattern symbols are supported.

*: Matches everything
?: Matches any single character
[sequence]: Matches any character in sequence
[!sequence]: Matches any character not in sequence
```

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters

Given your example, the correct call should be:

```
aws s3 cp data/ s3://bucket-name/data/201707/ --recursive --exclude 'data/new/*' --exclude 'data/new1/*'
```

Comment: Thanks, Luke - I still see the same issue with above command too.

Comment: Are you removing the old, unwanted folders from s3 first? This command will not sync and remove them.

Comment: It turns out the question already had the `*` at the end of the exclude path, it just wasn't rendering because it wasn't in backticks or a code block.  Asterisk is, of course, a markdown character.  Formatting isn't just important for legibility; it sometimes affects the *meaning* of the content.  Please use your backticks and code blocks, ladies and gentlemen.

Comment: @Luke - s3 destination folder is new folder - it doesn't include anything.

Answer (score 1):

The exclude path is relative to `data/` in your case, so you don't want to specify it again via `--exclude`:

```
aws s3 cp data/ s3://<BUCKET_NAME>/data/201707/ --recursive --exclude "201707/new/*" --exclude "201707/new1/*"
```

This will copy the files in `data/201707/` to `s3://bucket/data/201707/201707/`  Maybe this is what you want, but if it isn't, you may want to remove the `201707` from the destination folder:

```
aws s3 cp data/ s3://<BUCKET_NAME>/data/ --recursive --exclude "201707/new/*" --exclude "201707/new1/*"
```

will copy the files in `data/201707/` to `s3://bucket/data/201707/`.

---

*Note:* On Windows, I need to use double quotes for the exclude pattern.  Single quotes don't work.

Comment: Mike, I have edited the question, the data/201707 has the files and new,new1 folders. I want to copy only the files to 201707, not the folders and its content(new, new1 )

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar requirement, this works for me.
this works -

```
aws s3 cp data/ s3://bucket-name/data/201707/ --recursive --exclude 'data/new/*' --exclude 'data/new1/*'
```

but i did it little differently. 
first i find the files i need and put them to a tmp or a different folder

```
export files_found=`find $file_path -type f -name "*.txt" -mtime -1 -printf "%f\n"`
```

if you want to make your path as a variable, that will be good

```
mkdir -p $your_path/today_files
```

then

```
cp $files_found /tmp/today_files
```

now the s3 cp will work easily

```
aws s3 cp /tmp/today_files s3://$bucket_name/folder_name --recursive --region us-east-1`
```

Then clean up your folder. This will make sure that we have only copied the files that we need in s3. 
Hope this works..

Answer (score 1):

Copying from data/201707/ and excluding from that level works for me:

```
aws s3 cp data/201707/ s3://bucket-name/data/201707/ --recursive --exclude "new/*" --exclude "new1/*"
```